Why does IBitwiseOperators not allow short-circuiting operators in a generic function?
In the process of investigating a .NET API proposal, to add the new System.Numerics interfaces to System.Boolean, it transpired that && and || short-circuiting operators need the operators true and false to be implemented.
I tried to test doing so with an interface containing the static abstract operators (a new feature for .NET 7):
public interface ITruthOperators<TSelf>
    where TSelf : ITruthOperators<TSelf>?
{
    static abstract bool operator true(TSelf left);

    static abstract bool operator false(TSelf left);
            
    static abstract TSelf operator !(TSelf left);

    static abstract TSelf TruthyIdentity { get; }
            
    static abstract TSelf FalseyIdentity { get; }
}

And a custom boolean type:
public struct MyBool(bool val) : ITruthOperators<MyBool>, IBitwiseOperators<MyBool, MyBool, MyBool>
{
    public bool Value {get;} = val;
    
    public static bool operator true(MyBool b) => b.Value;
    
    public static bool operator false(MyBool b) => !b.Value;
    
    public static MyBool operator !(MyBool b) => new(!b.Value);

    public static MyBool TruthyIdentity => new(true);
    
    public static MyBool FalseyIdentity => new(false);
    
    public static MyBool operator &(MyBool a, MyBool b) => new(a.Value & b.Value);
    
    public static MyBool operator |(MyBool a, MyBool b) => new(a.Value | b.Value);
    
    public static MyBool operator ^(MyBool a, MyBool b) => new(a.Value ^ b.Value);
    
    public static MyBool operator ~(MyBool val) => new(!val.Value);
}

You can now write something like if (T.TruthyIdentity) or if (!someMyBool). You can also use non-short-circuiting operators someMyBool & someOtherMyBool
But using short-circuiting operators still do not work.
public T IsTrue<T>(T a, T b) where T : ITruthOperators<T>, IBitwiseOperators<T, T, T>
{
    return a && b;
}

just gets you:
In order to be applicable as a short circuit operator a user-defined logical operator ('IBitwiseOperators<T, T, T>.operator &(T, T)') must have the same return type and parameter types

This makes no sense, because the operator & defined on IBitwiseOperators<TSelf, TOther, TResult> is defined as
public static abstract TResult operator & (TSelf left, TOther right);

so if you re-ify the generic type as IBitwiseOperators<MyBool, MyBool, MyBool> then you get:
public static abstract MyBool operator & (MyBool left, MyBool right);

See fiddle.

I tried to redefine my own IBitwiseOperators<TSelf> where all the parameters and return types are the same generic parameter, in case that was the issue.
public interface IBitwiseOperators<TSelf>
    where TSelf : IBitwiseOperators<TSelf>?
{
    static abstract TSelf operator &(TSelf left, TSelf right);

    static abstract TSelf operator |(TSelf left, TSelf right);

    static abstract TSelf operator ^(TSelf left, TSelf right);

    static abstract TSelf operator ~(TSelf value);
}

This got a different error:
In order for 'IBitwiseOperators<T>.operator &(T, T)' to be applicable as a short circuit operator, its declaring type 'IBitwiseOperators<T>' must define operator true and operator false

Which again makes no sense, because T in the function is constrained to both IBitwiseOperators and ITruthOperators.
The only way I could get this to work was if I placed all the operators in the same interface. See this fiddle for that attempt which finally worked.

Note the definition for short-circuiting operators in the C# Spec:

When the operands of && or || are of types that declare an applicable user-defined operator & or operator |, both of the following shall be true, where T is the type in which the selected operator is declared:

The return type and the type of each parameter of the selected operator shall be T. In other words, the operator shall compute the logical AND or the logical OR of two operands of type T, and shall return a result of type T.
T shall contain declarations of operator true and operator false.

A binding-time error occurs if either of these requirements is not satisfied. Otherwise, the && or || operation is evaluated by combining the user-defined operator true or operator false with the selected user-defined operator:
etc...

What do the words "where T is the type in which the selected operator is declared" mean here? Does that mean the interface, or does it mean the generic type? I think it should mean the generic type. Remember we are dealing with a generic type that is constrained to those interfaces, the variables we are handling are actually of type T.
So what I'm essentially asking is: is this a bug in the compiler, or is this by design?

I'd suggest submitting an issue to the dotnet repo if you haven't already. I reckon you are more likely to get a more helpful response there.

Question is: is this even a bug? Or am I just misreading the spec?
